# How to multiply 2 Binary Numbers?

Tags: summation, binary, decimal-expansion

Suppose I have two regular numbers $a$ and $b$ in base $10$ like this: (where $N$ is even)

$$a=a_{\frac N2}a_{\frac N2-1}\ldots a_1,\qquad b=b_{\frac N2}b_{\frac N2-1}\ldots b_1$$

So the result of their multiplication is:

$$a\cdot b=a_{\frac N2}a_{\frac N2-1}\ldots a\cdot b_{\frac N2}b_{\frac N2-1}\ldots b_1=\sum_{i=1}^{\frac N2}\sum_{j=1}^{\frac N2}(a_ib_j)10^{i+j-2}$$

---

Now suppose $a=a_Na_{N-1}...a_1$ and $b=b_Nb_{N-1}...b_1$ are (unsigned) binary numbers, such that each digit is actually 16 bits by its own. For example: $a_1$ can be: $1111010101000000$

So if $a$ has $N$ digits it's actually: $16N$ long binary number.

Given this fact how can I multiply them in a similar way to what is shown above?

**Why I need this?**

I want to multiply big numbers using the fact that I know only to multiply 16 bits binary numbers.

---

Small But Different Example:

if $a_M, b_M, a_L, b_L$ are all 16 bits binary numbers then I could use this fact to multiply 32 bits numbers like this:

[image]

Comment: The point of my question is to write the answer using those representatives of 16 bits.

Comment: Could you use $2^{16}$ instead of $10$ in the formula, would that be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base $10$, the digit $a_1$ can take values from $0$ to $9$. Any numbers higher than that can only displayed if you also use $a_2$.
In your setting, $a_1$ can take values from $0$ to $65535$ (which is $1111111111111111$ in binary). Any numbers higher than that can only displayed if you also use $a_2$.
So, in summary, we should consider base $65536$ (instead of base $10$).

The formula becomes
$$a\cdot b=a_{\frac N2}a_{\frac N2-1}\ldots a\cdot b_{\frac N2}b_{\frac N2-1}\ldots b_1=\sum_{i=1}^{\frac N2}\sum_{j=1}^{\frac N2}(a_ib_j)65536^{i+j-2},$$
where instead of $65536^{i+j-2}$
we can also write $(2^{16})^{i+j-2}$, which is the same as $2^{16 (i+j-2)}$.
The number $16 (i+j-2)$ in the exponent of the last expressions
is the number of bits that you need to shift by. to do (because if you multiply by $2^k$ this corresponds to a shift by $k$ bits).

Comment: May I understand why 16(+−2)  and not just (+−2)?

Comment: @math_calc sorry I had a typo. Basically, because $65536^{i+j-2}=2^{16(i+j-2)}$.

Comment: 1) Please fix the power it should be 16 not 1 2) can you elaborate why you considered number of possibilities at all? In base 10 I wrote 10 because this is how the base is, first number is 10^0 second is 10^1 and so on....

Comment: @math_calc corrected the typo. I added some explanation. Its basically one more than the highest number that $a_1$ can display.

Comment: Thanks, I had this question on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/542096/how-to-multiply-2-numbers too and in comments someone told me to use shift(+−2) which contradicts this, can you kindly take a look

Comment: @math_calc they probably misunderstood your question and thought only wanted to know about base $2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118346/discussion-between-math-calc-and-supinf).

Answer (score -1):

Replace $10$ by the base $b$,
either 2 or 16 or whatever to get

$a\cdot b=a_{\frac N2}a_{\frac N2-1}\ldots a\cdot b_{\frac N2}b_{\frac N2-1}\ldots b_1=\sum_{i=1}^{\frac N2}\sum_{j=1}^{\frac N2}(a_ib_j)b^{i+j-2}
$.

If $b=2$,
$b^{i+j-2}$ does
$i+j-2$ left shifts.

If $b=16$,
$b^{i+j-2}$ does
$4(i+j-2)$ left shifts.

Comment: That's not correct, I know I should use shift function here... please see my updated question

Comment: This does not seem to match with the question